# Error: Failed linking file resources. Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After Migrate my Xamarin Android app with AndroidX. This error is coming.

> Error:    failed linking file resources.  ZZAPP.Android
> Error:  attribute drawableStartCompat not found.

> Error:    attribute drawableLeftCompat not found.

This is my 1st layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >
</NumberPicker>
        
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker_month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
</NumberPicker>

<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
</NumberPicker>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my 2nd layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/number_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</NumberPicker>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please add the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in to the xml, such as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And then you can try again, if still not working, you can try to update the version of the material package.

**Update**

I had test on my ptoject:

1. Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources 1.3.1.1
2. Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2291
3. Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.4.0.2
4. Visual Studio 2022 17.3.0 proview 2.0

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246601/discussion-on-answer-by-liyun-zhang-msft-error-failed-linking-file-resources).